# Excel Query: Binding Adjacent Cells

Tags: excel

Apologies if my explanation is unclear. Without getting to into the backstory, I have created queries for existing units by sales territory (filtered by a list of states). Each row represents one unit and the information associated with that unit.

Sales would like a column to input a notes column and therein lies the problem. When source data is updated, the rows in the query move, but the note for that unit does not move with it. Is it possible to "bind" that note cell to the row?

Answer (score 1):

A query is a reporting technique. Data should never be entered into a report. If comments are entered against data from a report, then the query that feeds that report should never be refreshed. For exactly the reasons you state.

Data entry and reporting should be completely separate.

You may want to re-think your information architecture, or discuss the requirements with the report users some more. Maybe they can live with a one-off report that doesn't refresh? Then run the report and use VBA to copy/paste the data (not the query) into a new workbook and let them work on that.

When the report is refreshed, another copy is created.

If they really need the notes in the report, then these notes need to be entered at the source of the report, not in the report result.

I realize this is not what you want to hear, but this is how Excel and queries work.

Comment: Thank you for your response.